# Insert data in next empty column when "sheet.range" column is not empty

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below code to populate a table with weekly data via an index match function through VBA.

In the 1st week, column C of the Weekly sheet needs to be populated and this works like a charm.

However, starting from the 2nd week when new data is provided, I will need to make sure not to overwrite 1st week data and add new data into the next column which should be D. And so on.

Any suggestion about how to accomplish this objective with the below code?

```
Sub IndexMatchFunctionDynamic()
Dim destinationWs As Worksheet, dataWs As Worksheet
Dim destinationLastRow As Long, dataLastRow As Long, x As Long
Dim IndexRng As Range, MatchRng As Range

Set destinationWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Weekly")
Set dataWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Market Data")

destinationLastRow = destinationWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
dataLastRow = dataWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set IndexRng = dataWs.Range("P3:P" & dataLastRow)
Set MatchRng = dataWs.Range("A3:A" & dataLastRow)

For x = 2 To destinationLastRow

On Error Resume Next
a = Application.Match(destinationWs.Range("A" & x).Value, MatchRng, 0)
Nights = Application.Index(IndexRng, a)
If (IsError(a) Or IsEmpty(Nights)) Or (IsError(a) And IsEmpty(Nights)) Then
       
destinationWs.Range("C" & x).Value = 0

Else
destinationWs.Range("C" & x).Value = Nights
End If
On Error GoTo 0
Next x
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at modifying your row code `destinationLastRow = destinationWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` for columns?

Comment: actually the part of code that I think should be modified is the following one: destinationWs.Range("C" & x).Value = Nights. Here I am just saying to put data in range C until the last row but what I would need to check if range C (being the 1st one) is not empty and if it's not, then add data in range D and so on.

Comment: Yes, i get that, so maybe use the idea behind the last row finding, for the last column.

Comment: When there is data in C, why not insert a new column before C  The data will then be moved to column D and  the new data can be placed into the new column C.

Comment: I tried to work on this and this is what I have at the moment:  I added "lCol As Long" and  lCol = Range(Range("A2"), Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count)).Find(What:="*", _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column +1                                                                      and then: destinationWs.Range("lCol" & x) = Nights but this is the error I get: Method "Range of Object" _Worksheet failed. how  I can I use the lCol value in my destinationWs.Range("lCol" & x) = Nights?

Comment: @Kurt  Raghu got it :)

Answer (score 1):

First get next available column in the sheet

PrintToColumn =
destinationWs.Cells(1,Columns.Count).XlEnd(XlToLeft).Column + 1

Then print values in that column

destinationWs.Cells(x, PrintToColumn).Value = Nights

Comment: it gives me an error saying: Runtime error 438 - Object doesnt support this property or method :-(

Comment: I made it: lCol = Range(Range("A2"), Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count)).Find(What:="*", _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column + 1

ColLetter = Split(Cells(1, lCol).Address, "$")(1)